# Xcode SwiftUI how to scroll the Preview Canvas?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have started working with SwiftUI Demo.

But I am not able to scroll the Preview canvas in Xcode.

Yes there is button for zooming like -  100 + .

I have seen a video where person is scrolling this canvas during the tutorial

is there any option in Xcode to enable scrolling in preview canvas ?

[image]

Comment: It's working fine for me. The only situation when the scroller does not act, is if Live Preview is on, and the mouse pointer is inside the device box. I'm using beta2.

Comment: It's a macOS X Catalina's bug. Try restart your mac and all gestures (scroll, pinch and etc.) will work

Comment: Facing the same issue :(

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya and Plutomen what devices are you using? I'm also experiencing this issue with a Mac-Mini and bluetooth windows mouse.

Just trying to figure out what the commonality is between people experiencing the issue.

Comment: @JamieButler using Mac mini with usb mouse 
Don't know how other people are able to scroll

Comment: I can't scroll, either. I'm using a Mac mini and a Logitech USB mouse.

Comment: On my MacBook Air, I have a USB mouse with a scroll wheel. Running catalina and xcode 11, I cannot scroll with the scroll wheel, but I can scroll with my trackpad on my actual mac. This seems to be a bug related to trackpad vs USB mouse.

Comment: Scrolling doesn't work in Selectable mode.

Answer (score 5):

Seems to be a trackpad vs mouse wheel issue. Try scrolling with the trackpad, it should work until Apple gets this bug patched. Haven't tried with a bluetooth trackpad, might be worth looking into.

Comment: in my case, it does not work with the trackpad either

Answer (score 5):

In xcode 14.3, it is only scrollable in the right mode only.

Please kindly check the bottom left of the preview canvas. You should see few icons to change canvas mode, where

1. youtube play icon : it is the default interactive mode - NOT SCROLLABLE
2. an arrow that enclosed by a square icon - **SCROLLABLE**

As mentioned above, to scroll, you simply applies 2 finger gesture to swipe the screen as you like, surprisingly it is pretty intuitive when you are in the right mode. Since it is user-unfriendly to aware the behaviors of different modes, murky).

Comment: This was driving me crazy. Thanks. Not sure why it wouldn't be scrollable in the normal "Live" mode.....but you're right.

Answer (score 0):

On my MacBook Pro (Big Sur, 11.2.3), I place two fingers on the trackpad and move them up and down to scroll between previews in the canvas of Xcode 12.5 beta 3.

Hope that helps. I'm new to Mac to perhaps this was just obvious to everyone else.